# Keep window on top in Delphi or Java

Tags: java, delphi, user-interface

Is it possible in Delphi to keep a window on top of all other windows? For example when you have an error message in your application, let's say you want to keep the window on top and make sure the user has to click something before he can do anything else. And I really mean anything, like clicking another program in the background. And how about in Java?

Comment: [No, you **can't** do this!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx)

Comment: Even if you can, your users will kill you.

Comment: @GameCat - see my reply to Ken.

Comment: Thanks for all the great replies! Now let's forget about other programs, how would it work within the same application? Or is that also bad practise?

Comment: If you only care about your own program you can just use `ShowModal` instead of `Show`. This is still bad style, but only because it blocks the rest of the application, and that's what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Raymond Chen of Microsoft has a great article about why not [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx). The gist of it is that no matter how hard you try to keep your window on top, someone else can always come along and do the same thing.

Comment: great answer, but sometimes customers have brilliant ideas, and you need to satisfy them...even it's wrong!

Comment: @Radu Barbu: If Windows won't allow it, you can't, whether the customer wants it or not.

Comment: From the article: `This is like saying, "Sometimes I'm in a hurry, and I want to make sure I am the next person to get served at the deli counter. To do this, I find whoever has the lowest number, knock them unconscious, and steal their ticket. But sometimes somebody else comes in who's also in a hurry. That person knocks me unconscious and steals my ticket. My plan is to set my watch alarm to wake me up periodically, and each time it wakes me up, I find the person with the lowest number, knock them unconscious, and steal their ticket. Is there a better way?"`

Comment: I'd advise putting some info directly in your answer in case off-site resource becomes lost.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the old days. It was called a system modal dialog and you used the now obsolete `SetSysModalWindow()` function.

They were utterly repugnant and so sense and order was restored when Windows NT based versions of Windows took over.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi you can do `FormStyle:=fsStayOnTop;`. This will put you in front of all normal windows.

But if there are other windows which have that style set too(such as the task-bar) those might be on in front of yours. In particular among those windows the one that has focus is has the highest priority.

You can try to ensure that your window always has focus, but that's rarely a good idea. And you will incur the wraith of Raymond.

You can also use a layered window. I think those are in front of normal always-on-top windows. But this has severe side effects and is most likely not the correct choice for you.

Comment: OP says "like clicking another program in the background" so fsStayOnTop doesn't get it done. In fact it's pointless anyway because the dialog is presumably modal (i.e. app-modal) and so is on top of that apps windows anyway.

Comment: If the other program hasn't AlwaysOnTop set it will keep the OP's program in front of that other program.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, true, but it is still possible for other windows to get focus. You can do dirty tricks by capturing the mouse, but prepare for torches and pitchforks.

Comment: @CodeInChaos It doesn't matter who is on top, it's whether or not a window can receive input.

Comment: fsStayOnTop only controls the Z-Order in your own application. It has nothing to do with the ability to click on other applications and bring them forward.

Comment: @Ken No `fsStayOnTop` puts you on top of most other windows, even when those have focus and are in another application. And since it's on top it can receive mouse input, but of course no keyboard input since it has no focus.

Comment: @Code @Ken z-order is system wide not app-wide. To stay on top can place you above an other app's forms. But it's easy to get those forms out of the way and interact with them.